# reverse array when using prompt

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

So I've got this and I need it to come up in reverse order. I have tried .reverse(); but still couldn't manage to make it work. Can someone help please?

```
<button onclick="result()">Click here</button>
<script>
function result()
{
    var i          =  0;
    var outMessage = "";
    var studNames  = new Array(5);
    var studMarks  = new Array(5);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        studNames[i] = prompt('Enter next name - ' , "");
        studMarks[i] = prompt('Enter next mark - ' ,  0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        outMessage = outMessage + studNames[i] + studMarks[i] + "\n";
    }

    alert (outMessage);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please tell exactly what is needed? Do you want names and marks to be added to outMessage in reverse order?

Answer (score 2):

Inverse the for loop.

```
for (i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
    outMessage = outMessage + studNames[i] + studMarks[i] + "\n";
alert(outMessage);
```